# What is this syntax: $[] - it’s referenced in Serverless Framework docs but not explained in the Variables section

Tags: serverless-framework

There are several references using $[...] syntax in the serverless-plugin-aws-alerts [docs](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-aws-alerts): Serverless Framework: Plugins

I understand about ${…} variables from the relevant [docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables): Serverless Framework Variables

But I can’t find anything to describe what is happening in the below code snippet (taken from the aws-alerts plugin docs linked above)

```yaml
nameTemplate: $[functionName]-Duration-IMPORTANT-Alarm # Optionally - naming template for the alarms, overwrites globally defined one
prefixTemplate: $[stackName] # Optionally - override the alarm name prefix, overwrites globally defined one
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-aws-alerts It's described here, under Custom Naming:

- You can define a custom naming template for the alarms.
- `nameTemplate` property under `alerts` configures naming template for all the alarms, while placing `nameTemplate` under alarm definition configures (overwrites) it for that specific alarm only. Naming template provides interpolation capabilities, where supported placeholders are:

  - `$[functionName]` - function name (e.g. `helloWorld`)
  - `$[functionId]` - function logical id (e.g. `HelloWorldLambdaFunction`)
  - `$[metricName]` - metric name (e.g. `Duration`)
  - `$[metricId]` - metric id (e.g. `BunyanErrorsHelloWorldLambdaFunction` for the log based alarms, `$[metricName]` otherwise)

> Note: All the alarm names are prefixed with stack name (e.g. `fooservice-dev`).

So

```yaml
alerts:
  nameTemplate: $[functionName]-$[metricName]-Alarm # configures names for all alarms
alerts:
  alarms:
 definitions: 
      customAlarm:
        nameTemplate: $[functionName]-Duration-IMPORTANT-Alarm  # configures (overwrites) it for that specific alarm only.
```